# Javascript / Dynamically append text element above embedded facebook posts

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am building an HTML/CSS/Javascript application that dynamically embeds facebook posts based on an API that returns a list of facebook post ID's. I loop through the post ID's, generate an embed code with postId inserted for each post, and append to the DOM. Simple stuff.

However I need to append some simple text above each post, and I cannot figure out how to do this dynamically in Javascript.

**UPDATE 3.28**
I know that I cannot append anything to the iframe generated by the embed code, and that I have to append the text before or after the iframe element as mentioned in comments below. I updated my code below so that the additional text is being appended to the parent container for the posts, as opposed to trying to append to the iframe itself.

This works as far as getting the text to appear on the page, but I'm getting a list of text elements that appear after all the iframe elements, as opposed to one text element for each iframe. See below for screenshots of what is generated:

[image: What appears on the page]
[image: Resulting code in inspector]

```js
// Array of facebook post ID's
facebookArr = [{
    post_id: "pfbid0cm7x6wS3jCgFK5hdFadprTDMqx1oYr6m1o8CC93AxoE1Z3Fjodpmri7y2Qf1VgURl"
  },
  {
    post_id: "pfbid0azgTbbrM5bTYFEzVAjkVoa4vwc5Fr3Ewt8ej8LVS1hMzPquktzQFFXfUrFedLyTql"
  }
];

// Variables to store post ID, embed code, parent container
let postId = "";
let embedCode = "";
let facebookContainer = document.getElementById("facebook-feed-container");
$(facebookContainer).empty();

// Loop through data to display posts
facebookArr.forEach((post) => {
  let relativeContainer = document.createElement("div");

  postId = post.post_id;

  postLink = `${postId}/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading`;

  // ---> UPDATE: separate container element
  let iframeContainer = document.createElement("div");

  embedCode = `<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FIconicCool%2Fposts%2F${postId}&show_text=true&width=500" width="200" height="389" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" id=fb-post__${postId}></iframe>`;

  // Update the DOM
  iframeContainer.innerHTML = embedCode;

  // ADDITIONAL TEXT
  let additionalText = document.createElement("div");

  additionalText.className = "absolute";
  additionalText.innerText = "additional text to append";

  relativeContainer.append(additionalText, iframeContainer);
  facebookContainer.append(relativeContainer);
});
```

```css
#facebook-feed-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  column-gap: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="facebook-feed-container"></div>
```

Comment: You can not append anything _into_ the iframe - it is loaded from a different origin, so you have _no_ JavaScript access to its contents at all. You could only add stuff to your own document, before or after the iframe element. If you need it to partially overlap the iframe content(?), then position it absolute.

Comment: This is so helpful. I will try this and report back if I have questions. Much appreciated!

Comment: @CBroe - Interesting, I'm able to add the additional text elements before the iframe element, and absolute positioning gets the text exactly over the element like I wanted.  However, the text is only visible on the FIRST instagram post, instead of above each post... not sure how to handle this?

Comment: Are you talking about the code as currently shown above, or did you modify it? Because in what's currently showing here, you are trying to append the additional text to the `iframe` elements, and that doesn't make much sense. (Children of iframe elements would only be shown as fallback content, if the browser wasn't capable of handling iframes in the first place.)

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for being unclear. I modified my code so that I am no longer trying to append to the iframe element. Instead, I am appending text to the same parent container that I append the posts to, and then positioning the text as "absolute" per your suggestion.  I still cannot figure out how to get a scenario where I am appending one text element for each post...as opposed to a list of text elements that appear after all the iframe elements. See modified code in my post above and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Put each iframe and the additional text into a separate container element - and position that container relative, so that it becomes the reference point for absolute positioned children.

Comment: @CBroe Ok -- I tried implementing that, but I'm getting the same result as before. I updated the code in my post, any chance you could check and see if if there's something I'm doign wrong in regards to your suggestion?

Comment: Check the resulting DOM, using your browser dev tools - you currently created two `relative` elements containing an iframe each, and then _following_ those, you got two `absolute` elements. The absolute elements need to go _into_ the relative containers, not be appended after them. (This would probably be a bit easier, if you did both things in _one_ loop.)

Comment: Ah, finally I'm understanding...WOW thanks again. https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/dyLzLNV?editors=1111

Comment: One last issue I'm having is getting the text positioned ABOVE the post, and not directly overlayed on the top of it. I can't seem to write any styling rules that push the text up, nor the post down. Any thoughts? Here's a codepen example: https://codepen.io/Mickey_Vershbow/pen/dyLzLNV?editors=1111

Comment: Structure is still wrong. Now you have each "absolute", and each iframe, in _separate_ wrapper divs.